# kotlin : Not able to call interface method with inheritance

Tags: android, inheritance, interface, kotlin

I have an interface defined like this

```
interface ScannerAdapter<in P> where P : ScanParameters {
    fun scan(scanParameters: P): Single<Boolean>
}
```

Now I have an Adapter class

```
class Type1ScannerAdapter: ScannerAdapter<Type1ScanParameters> {

    override fun scan(printParameters: Type1ScanParameters): Single<Boolean> {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

}
```

The `Type1ScanParameters` is

```
sealed class ScanParameters

data class Type1ScanParameters(val somethingProbably: Unit): ScanParameters()
```

Now when I try to call the `scan` function on a `Type1ScannerAdapter` instance I am getting the error as

> scan(capture) cannot be applied to scan(...ScanParamteres)

How I am calling the function:

I have an adapter factory that returns the Type1ScannerAdapter instance ( based on some logic)
So i am calling

```
adapterFactory.getAdapter().scan(getParams(scannerType))




     private ScanParameters getParams(int scanType) {
        switch(scanType){
            case xyz:
                return new Type1ScanParameters(....);
//            
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: could you please add some code to show how you call the `scan` function and the parameter that you pass to this function?

Comment: updated about how scan is called

Comment: Just curious: what is `Single`? From the name, I get the feeling that whatever it does might already exist in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

So far as static types go, `getParams(scannerType)` just returns `ScanParameters`, the compiler has no idea if it happens to be `Type1ScanParameters` at runtime.

So if you know

> I have an adapter factory that returns the Type1ScannerAdapter instance ( based on some logic)

then `getParams` has to return `Type1ScanParameters`.